# Chef-server install on 32bits system

Tags: chef-infra

I need to install chef-server on a ubuntu 14.04 i386 machine.

I see on `http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/` only packages for some older versions of amd64 Ubuntu. On `https://rubygems.org/gems/chef-server` I only see an outdated version of chef-server.

For me, the gems are the best way to install...

How could I install it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest contacting [chef](http://www.getchef.com/) (the company formerly known as opscode).

The [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/api_omnitruck.html) suggests that Ubuntu i386 is not a supported platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for chef-server on i386 machine.There has been a documentation bug in Opscode,which has been corrected recently.

Below is the link for your reference

https://github.com/opscode/chef-docs/commit/fd16e4f5e2d950dc31c75ea53acf417df61a9d90